# Include VS DLL in non-VS project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, dll

I don't have much experience with either writing DLLs or Visual Studio.  Basically I want to use a DLL created in Visual Studio in a non-VS (namely, Qt) project.  The `.h` file for the default DLL  (VS2010) is:

```
// test-lib.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace testlib {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        //...
    };
}
```

I'm able to build the DLL without any problem, but I don't know how to include it in my Qt project.  That is, when I try to compile it I get

> ..\test-lib.h:6: error: C2871: 'System' : a namespace with this name
>   does not exist ..\test-lib.h:10: error: C2059: syntax error : 'public'
>   ..\test-lib.h:11: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
>   etc.

This is despite the fact that I'm compiling with VS2012's compiler and my version of Qt was built with it as well.  Does anyone know how I can make this work?  In my `.pro` file I currently have the dll added to `LIBS`, are there other dlls I need to add?

Comment: Your question is tagged `C++` however the code is not. Do you want to use a .dll with native code or a managed .NET assembly from your Qt project?

Comment: @Tim I want my Qt code to be as Windows-free as possible.  So no .NET or whatever within Qt if that's possible.  Nothing against VS I just need portability.  I'm using VS2012 C++ so I assume that what I'm working with is mostly C++, with a layer on top for whatever preprocessing VS does (as Qt has an MOC layer).  So I think the C++ tag is reasonable, as Qt is C++-based and the `#include` syntax is C/C++-specific

Comment: I'm still confused. While an `#include` preprocessor directive is indeed C++, the header file _test-lib.h_ is not. It looks like C++/CLI which - as far as syntax is concerned - is a superset of C++. However it does not compile to native code and running it requires the .NET runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your DLL written in C with symbol exports and etc.

```
typedef void (*NameOfMyDLLFunction)(double* data, int size);
QLibrary* myLibrary = new QLibrary("NameOfMyLibraryFile", this);

myLibrary->load();

NameOfMyDLLFunction dllFunction = reinterpret_cast<NameOfMyDLLFunction(myLibrary->resolve("dllFunction "));
```

Now you can call your `dllFunction(double* data, int size)`.